# Deserialize array from query string in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, parameters, deserialization

I have the following query string:

```
?rooms[0][adult]=2&rooms[0][children]=3,4&rooms[1][adult]=3
```

Is there any direct method in AngularJS or vainilla Javascript to get the following object from it:

```
[
   {
      adult: 2,
      children: [3, 4]
   },
   {
      adult: 3,
   }
]
```

Or do I have to implement a particular deserializer for this case?

Comment: Are you using $location service in defining your route/path? Can you provide how are you arriving at this path? (Will help us answer the most efficient way to do this.)

Comment: With this I make a GET request to a PHP endpoint trough Ajax. Then I put the query string in the search input of the browser with '$location.search(<queryString>') in case the user will reload the page and to get the same the result I have to parse that query string to that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

What I did was:

1. Get the query string as an object with `$location.search()`
2. Iterate trough the query string object.
3. Use the RegEx `/rooms\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]/` to get the index of the array and the key of the inner object when matching with a query string object key.

The algorithm is:

```
let queryString = $location.search();
let regEx = /rooms\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]/;

let rooms = [{}];
for (let roomKey in queryString) {
    let matches = roomKey.match(regEx);
    if(matches) {
        let index = parseInt(matches[1]);
        let key = matches[2];
        if(key == 'adult') {
            rooms[index] = {
                adult: queryString[roomKey]
            }
        }
        else if (key == 'children') {
            rooms[index] = {
                children: queryString[roomKey] == "" ? [] : queryString[roomKey].split(',')
            }
        }
    }
}
```